# Modify DATE in COLUMN using CASES and LOOP

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I have One month data.

```
DATE       | AMOUNT
04/01/2019 | 3437824
04/02/2019 | 234834
04/03/2019 | 2343478
.
.
.
04/30/2019 | 343729
```

I want to change the Date Column to give me something like this

```
OLDDATE    | DATE       | AMOUNT
04/01/2019 | 01/01/2019 | 3437824
04/02/2019 | 02/01/2019 | 234834
04/03/2019 | 03/01/2019 | 2343478
.
.
.
04/12/2019 | 12/01/2019 | 328456
04/13/2019 | 01/02/2019 |845754
04/14/2019 | 02/02/2019 |845754
.
.
04/24/2019 | 12/02/2019 |845754
04/25/2019 | 01/03/2019 |845754
04/26/2019 | 02/03/2019 |845754
.
.
.
04/30/2019 | 06/03/2019 | 343729
```

I tried to achieve the same using a switch case inside a while loop but was not able to get the desired result

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @Mth INT = 1;
DECLARE @Iteration INT = 1;

WHILE @Iteration != 1000000
    BEGIN
        WHILE @Mth <= 12
            BEGIN
                UPDATE TACC
                SET BUSINESSDATE = 
                CASE 
                    WHEN DAY([BUSINESSDATE])<13  
                    THEN datefromparts(year([BUSINESSDATE]), @Mth, 1)  
                    WHEN DAY([BUSINESSDATE]) BETWEEN 13 AND 24 
                    THEN datefromparts(year([BUSINESSDATE]), @Mth, 2) 
                    ELSE datefromparts(year([BUSINESSDATE]), @Mth, 3)
                END
                SET @Mth = @Mth + 1 
                IF @Mth=13 
                    BEGIN   
                        SET @Mth=1
                    END
            END
        SET @Iteration = @Iteration + 1
    END
END
```

Which will be the better way to do it T-SQL or DAX if i have to do this for say 10 million rows

Comment: What does this have to do with `DAX`?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, we need to divide the rows in groups of `12` and for each group to increase the month part of the new date. The rows in the each groups need to be ordered and we need to increase the day part of each new date with one.

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to order the rows and divide them in groups. Then you can use `DATEADD` to built the new date for each row:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [DATE] DATETIME2(0)
   ,[AMOUNT] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([DATE], [AMOUNT])
VALUES ('2019-04-01', 100)
      ,('2019-04-02', 100)
      ,('2019-04-03', 100)
      ,('2019-04-04', 100)
      ,('2019-04-05', 100)
      ,('2019-04-06', 100)
      ,('2019-04-07', 100)
      ,('2019-04-08', 100)
      ,('2019-04-09', 100)
      ,('2019-04-10', 100)
      ,('2019-04-11', 100)
      ,('2019-04-12', 100)
      ,('2019-04-13', 100)
      ,('2019-04-14', 100)
      ,('2019-04-15', 100)
      ,('2019-04-16', 100)
      ,('2019-04-17', 100)
      ,('2019-04-18', 100)
      ,('2019-04-19', 100)
      ,('2019-04-20', 100)
      ,('2019-04-21', 100)
      ,('2019-04-22', 100)
      ,('2019-04-23', 100)
      ,('2019-04-24', 100)
      ,('2019-04-25', 100)
      ,('2019-04-26', 100)
      ,('2019-04-27', 100)
      ,('2019-04-28', 100)
      ,('2019-04-29', 100);

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME2 = '2019-01-01'
       ,@Step TINYINT = 12;

WITH DataSource ([OLDDATE], [AMOUNT], [AddMonth]) AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date] ASC) -1 ) / 12 
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT [OLDDATE] 
      ,[AMOUNT] 
      ,DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [AddMonth] ORDER BY [OLDDATE] ASC) - 1, DATEADD(MONTH, [AddMonth], @StartDate))
FROM DataSource;
```

[image]